# redux-observable epic with multiple filters

Tags: redux-observable

I am writing an epic using redux-observable and am trying to write an epic using multiple filters (oftype).  Given below is my sample code

```
export const landingEpic = action$ => {
    console.log('inside landing epic');
    return action$.ofType('APPLY_SHOPPING_LISTS').map(() => (
        {
            type: 'APPLYING_SHOPPING_LISTS',
        })
    );

    return action$.ofType('APPLIED_SHOPPING_LIST'){
      //here I want to return something else
    }
}
```

However I cannot have two return methods in one epic?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to combine them with `Observable.merge()` then return that--however I also highly suggest separating them into two separate epics. It will make it easier to test, but that's of course your call.

```
export const landingEpic = action$ => {
  return Observable.merge(
    action$.ofType('APPLY_SHOPPING_LISTS')
      .map(() => ({
        type: 'APPLYING_SHOPPING_LISTS',
      }),

    action$.ofType('APPLIED_SHOPPING_LIST')
      .map(() => ({
        type: 'SOMETHING_ELSE',
      }),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use [combineEpics](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/blob/master/docs/api/combineEpics.md):

```
import { combineEpics } from "redux-observable";

const landingEpic1 = // put epic1 definition here

const landingEpic2 = // put epic2 definition here

export default combineEpics(
    landingEpic1, 
    landingEpic2,
    // ...
);
```

Comment: Ideally it makes logical sense to have all of this in one epic, so therefore I want to have this in one.